# What is the worst-case running time for this algorithm?

Tags: c++, string, optimization

I'm studying some code for my Facebook interview.  I understand what this algorithm does, but I can't figure out its complexity.  This is what's stated on a [website](http://leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-i.html) I've visited:

> Since expanding a palindrome around its center could take O(N) time, the overall complexity is O(N^2).

Could someone explain to me how they got that running time, specifically the average and worst cases?

The problem given is to find the largest palindrome substring.  I'm kind of new to strings.

I also want to know if you guys think I should learn Manacher’s Algorithm, which is O(N).  It's a better solution that uses less memory, but it's really hard for me to understand.

```
string expandAroundCenter(string s, int c1, int c2) {
  int l = c1, r = c2;
  int n = s.length();
  while (l >= 0 && r <= n-1 && s[l] == s[r]) {
    l--;
    r++;
  }
  return s.substr(l+1, r-l-1);
}

string longestPalindromeSimple(string s) {
  int n = s.length();
  if (n == 0) return "";
  string longest = s.substr(0, 1);  // a single char itself is a palindrome
  for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    string p1 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i);
    if (p1.length() > longest.length())
      longest = p1;

    string p2 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i+1);
    if (p2.length() > longest.length())
      longest = p2;
  }
  return longest;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're asking us to review that piece of code, this question may be off-topic (and better suited for Stack Overflow).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about complexity

Comment: [tag:facebook] isn't relevant here, that one's about the use of their app platform.

Comment: @LokiAstari Also, better suited for [computerscience.se] than [so].

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds snarky, but you are interviewing (for what I imagine is a programmer/developer position) at Facebook and you can't figure out the running time of this algorithm in all of 10 seconds?

Comment: @Nik.  I'm with you on the snarkiness.  However, sadly, I have been finding more and more that colleges are graduating programmers who do not know how to do complexity analysis (O(n) and its friends).  

Giuseppe: I highly recommend wikipedia-ing big-O notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation ) before going any further.  We can tell you that this algorithm is O(n^2) with a worst case of a long string of identical characters, but that will not help you in the interview unless you know what O(things-go-in-here) means and understand why they are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Analysis of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) and a little bit of [this](https://www.google.com/#q=big+o+notation), then come back and see if the rest of my answer makes sense.

I'd check with an O(n) algorithm if the string itself is a palindrome before going ahead.

Let's see, you have a for loop that runs n times, at each iteration, you call a function that runs ... well, the worst possible case is that you always find the longest possible palindrome every time you call `expandAroundCenter` i.e the iteration runs until `l < 0 || r > n-1`. This implies that the algorithm is `O(min(i, n-i))`. Now if we find the sum from 1 to n of `min(i, n-i)`, we get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28i=0%29%5En%20min%28i,%20n-i%29&t=crmtb01), which is of O(n²).

Comment: Yep, that helped a lot. I code it yesterday and i wrote down each funtion's running time . First one its O(2n) and the second iterates all over again wich is of O(n^2).